How to derive the number of phase and angle parameters of the n-th order unitary matrix U(n)?
Within many sources, Wikipedia inclusively, there is a statement of kind "The unitary n×n CKM matrix is parametrized by $\frac{1}{2}n(n−1)$ real angles and $\frac{1}{2}n(n+1)$ complex phases". It is not specific to CMK matrix, however that parametrization appeares mainly there. What is meticulous way to derive it? It is easy to understand how it works for 2x2 matrix, however how to generalize it, is not clear to me and I found only statements not derivations.
2x2 unitary matrix U can be written in this form
$$U = e^{i\phi /2}\begin{pmatrix}
  e^{i\alpha} \cos{\theta}  & e^{i\beta} \sin{\theta}\\ 
  -e^{-i\beta} \sin{\theta} & e^{-i\alpha} \cos{\theta}
\end{pmatrix}$$
where $\alpha, \beta, \phi$ can be called phases and $\theta$ is angle accordingly to initial statement.
